# CSS how to style so that I can toggle another menu ABOVE the bootstrap navbar-fixed-top?

Tags: html, css

My app uses a bootstrap navbar-fixed-top.  However, we now need to show another menu that will toggle open/close ABOVE the navbar-fixed-top.

My issue is with the CSS.

In order to open this menu (which does look similar to a 100% width navbar, its about 40px height), should I be pushing the body down?  If I do that, the navbar-fixed-top still stays fixed to the top.

Or, is there another way to achieve this because I need to open this menu ABOVE the rest of the content.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: my code is literally `onToggleOffersMenu() { this.showOffersMenu = !this.showOffersMenu }`, and based on the state of `showOffersMenu`, I use ngClass to apply `.showOffersMenu { margin-top: 40px }`.  I am using angular 2.

Comment: My question is more about how to go about addressing this new requirement.  Because of the component design, I don't think I should be manipulating the body styling from my component.  However, if I was to open a menu above the `navbar-fixed-top`, would it be better to push the body down?  I just don't understand the requirement to be honest, it is kind of silly, but it is what it is :/

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to let the fixed navbar overlay the content you want to display. And make it move a fixed amount of pixels when an event is fired.

You can simply create a class containing the desired amount of pixels for the navbar to move and display the content above it. And, for example, when you click a button you add such class to your bootstrap navbar.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ozvk5rrh/1/

The CSS:

```
// styles the content above the navbar
.above {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.margin-top {
  top: 25px !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#showContent").click(function(){
    $("#myNavbar").toggleClass("margin-top")
;})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a easy task to apply just u have to have some bootstrap knowledge to implement the same.

Bootstrap uses this code for hamburger button:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
```

Bootstrap uses this code for show/hide element and menu:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

If you want multiple navs just you have to change the `data-target` of `button` and same `data-target` as the `id` of the div which you want to show/hide. You can also adjust the area of collapse by providing some padding or height to the collapse content.

You can also refer to this link for more information:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Thank You..